# Is a member of a temporary also a temporary?

Tags: c++, move, compiler-optimization

Given a function like:

```
Foo MakeFoo(const std::string& name);
```

we might expect the following to be move constructed, assuming a move constructor is defined for `Foo`, because the RHS is a temporary:

```
auto foo = MakeFoo("foo 1");
```

Does the same hold true for fields of temporaries? For example, in:

```
auto bar = MakeFoo("foo 2").bar;
```

assuming `decltype(Foo::bar)` has both copy and move construction defined, is it guaranteed to use one or the other, and does it depend in any way on compiler optimization level?